# Como adicionar uma constraint default em uma coluna já criada, no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

No SQL Server, supondo que a coluna já exista, como criar uma nova constraint DEFAULT? Eu procurei em várias referências e em todos os exemplos, sempre tinha a coluna para criar junto. Achei a pergunta interessante e gostaria de integrá-la a base de conhecimento do SOpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando é:

```
ALTER TABLE [schema].[tabela] 
  ADD  DEFAULT (([valor])) FOR [coluna]
```

Se preferir nomear a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [schema].[tabela]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [nome-da-constraint] DEFAULT [valor-padrao] FOR [coluna]
```

Ele até enriqueceu o artigo indicando ainda como excluir somente a constraint.

alter table [schema].[tabela] drop constraint [nome-da-constraint]

Encontrei a resposta em uma das respostas do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10843628/2788478)